# knockout.mapping plugin to map only certain properties

Tags: knockout.js

I want to use knockout mapping to map only a given list of properties and not other properties (that exists in model).

```
var propertiesToMap = ["PeriodStartDate", "PeriodEndDate", ...]
```

If I use `knockout.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, myModel)` all properties would be mapped.
I know I can add custom mapping `knockout.mapping.fromJS(data, customMapping, myModel)`, however, I do not know if there exists such option as "`mapOnlyGivenProperties`".
I know there is "`ignore`" property, but I want opposite functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'ignore' mappings option or write function, that filters only included properties (take a look at the code below).

```js
var mapping = {
    'ignore': ["ignoredProperty"]
}

var data = {
  propertyToInclude: 1,
  alsoIncludeThis: "str",
  ignoredProperty: "some val"
}

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
//debugger;
console.log(viewModel.alsoIncludeThis());
console.log(viewModel.ignoredProperty);



var includesList = ["propertyToInclude", "alsoIncludeThis"];

function leaveJustIncludedProperties(data, includesList) {
  var result = {};
  (includesList || []).forEach(function(propertyName) {
    result[propertyName] = data[propertyName];
  });
  return result;
}
var viewModel1 = ko.mapping.fromJS(leaveJustIncludedProperties(data, includesList), mapping);
//debugger;
console.log(viewModel1.alsoIncludeThis());
console.log(viewModel1.ignoredProperty);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
```

Comment: very nice solution